# Uncaught TypeError, on 'backspace' in Search

Tags: jquery, search, backspace

This code ties the searchTextChanged function to the input text field:

```
this.on('input', {
                searchTextSelector: this._searchTextChanged
            });
```

This function gets the value from the _getValueFromEventObject function and displays a trash icon when the value is larger than 0

```
this._searchTextChanged = function (evt) {
        var query = this._getValueFromEventObject(evt);
        this.select('searchArea').toggleClass('site-header-search-filled', query.length > 0);
        var payload = { 'query': query };
        this.trigger(document, 'data:search:query', payload);
    };
```

This function makes the input event value available:

```
    this._getValueFromEventObject = function (evt) {
        return evt.target ? (evt.target.value || evt.target[0].value) : '';
    };
```

The problem is if I remove the text from the input field with 'backspace', 
I get the following error:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

So the backspace event is undefined within this function, or?

Comment: no, the target is undefined.

Comment: but when I console.log the target, it is the text-field. any tips for how to debug + procede?

Comment: Hm, I'm really not sure, why this happens then.

Comment: What if you wrap it with a Try statement?

Comment: completely stuck. evt.target.value is undefined if I backspace to the begginning of the input text